# Display certain array data that matches database data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have been digging around trying to figure this out for a few days now. The issue is that I have a form that enters data into a MySQL database table and links that data to a service ID. The table contains 3 colums: `id` `serviceid` and `data`. I also have an array (working with a json API) that outputs all items (not linked to a service id) under `data`. What I am trying to do is match the service ID with the data, and then only display that specific data from the array.

In a nutshell, if I am viewing service #186, it has the 2 sets of data that I want to be able to pull from the array (not the db). It should only pull the array items (`[0]` and `[2]`) that match the table column `data` with the array item `["name"]`.

+------------+-----------+
| id| serviceid | data
+------------+-----------+
| 3 | 186 | SomeMore |
| 2 | 185 | NotEnough |
| 1 | 186 | Data5 |
+------------+-----------+

```
array {
  ["data_bits"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=> "Data5"
      ["info"]=> "some info"
      ["comment"]=> "cool beans"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=> "NotEnough"
      ["info"]=> "some cool info"
      ["comment"]=> "warm beans"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=> "SomeMore"
      ["info"]=> "some bad info"
      ["comment"]=> "hot beans"
    }
  }
```

Currently, I have the SQL query that will select the items that have the service ID.

```
$get = $pdo->prepare("SELECT data FROM table WHERE serviceid=:serviceid");
        $get->bindParam(':serviceid', $serviceid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $get->execute();
        $data_array = array();
        while ($db_data = $get->fetch()) {
            $data_array[] = $db_data[0];
        }
```

If I `echo $data_array[0];` in `foreach` statement, it show all data related to the current service.

Sorry if this doesn't make a lot of sense. It's rattling me insane. If you need a better explanation, i'll do what I can to try to clarify.

Comment: So if your query has serviceid=186 then you want to match the subarrays from your "data_bits" array that have in "name" field the values "Data5" and "SomeMore"?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? Just add a "continue" to your loop if the row you're working on isn't one you want.

Comment: @Ultimater This would only search the database table for the data. I need it to search the array for matching data from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search in `$data_bits` array to find those subarrays that have a name attribute which is one of the query results.

```
$get = $pdo->prepare("SELECT data FROM table WHERE serviceid=:serviceid");
$get->bindParam(':serviceid', $serviceid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$get->execute();
$result = $get->fetchAll();

$search_values = array();
$wanted_data = array();

foreach($result as $row) {
    $search_values[] = $row['data'];
}

foreach($data_bits as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value['data'], $search_values)) {
        $wanted_data[] = $data_bits[$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed! I have a second piece of this bit to work on (similar array items). I hope I can get it going with the information you have provided! Thank you.